# Getuser() method of Facebook PHP SDK always returns 0

Tags: facebook-graph-api

**Problem:** I am not able to get user id from Facebook's getuser() method.

**Description:** I have created a Facebook app. I have given site URL as "http://localhost:8088/fb/" After saving the changes. Now I want to get user id so that I can access user's information on Facebook.

Below is my code:

```
    <?php
require 'facebook.php';


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
 echo $user;
if($user)
{
 $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
 }
 else
{
 $logoutUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
 ?>
 <!doctype html>
 <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <head>
<title>php-sdk</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <?php if($user )
  {
?>
 <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
 <?php
  }
 else
 {
 ?>
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login</a>
<?php
  } 
  ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

After login to Facebook, I am getting user id equals to 0. Are there any settings that I need to perform? I have searched for many solutions but nothing works. How can I get the user id?

Comment: Also i modified the code to authroize the app. I used below code   $params = array(
'scope' => 'read_stream',
 'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:8088/fb/feeds.php'
       );
    and used it here
       $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginU($params);    A authorization dialog opens. bt even after authrozing the app, i didn't get user id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about PHP but the reason might be one of these:

1. You didn't authenticated your application.
2. You are running the app from localhost and provided the name in graph API as of your domain or something else.
3. Your access token is expired.

Comment: when you created the Facebook application related to your app, you should have provided the App Domains in application settings at Facebook Developers App section. If you are running your website or app on local server(or localhost) than you should provide App Domain there as localhost. Than Facebook will authenticate you.

Comment: I provided the app domain as local host in application settings. But the problem still persists...